# Check if rectangles intersect or is on the side of another (Android)

Tags: android, intersection, rectangles

I have a lot of rectangles, described using the top-left coordinate, where x increases as it goes right and y increases as it goes down. I need to find out whether the rectangles intersect with each other.

I drew my rectangles using Inkscape, and I computed them with x and y coordinates (the top-left of the rectangle), height, width, and stroke-width from the SVG file so there were a lot of computations I've done prior to this method so I was kind of assuming that I have to set a threshold or something alike before I could actually see if they intersect (which explains why I placed 0.001 in my code, but it was just a guess/test value).

When I drew them, I placed their x,y coordinates and I don't think they intersect but I'm assuming that the stroke-width would have an effect on their x,y coordinates.

I thought I could use **Java.Awt.Rectangle#intersects** method in Android but apparently, I can't. I also cannot use **android.graphics.Rect#intersects** because I am dealing with double and it only allows integers *and I also do not need it to be drawn on my screen*.

I have tried to create my own code for this based on what I've read online but the output isn't as what I expected, some of it are actually correct but there were a few errors. Below is the code I've tried.

```java
// x1_1, y1_1 = top-left coordinate of r1
// x1_2, y1_2 = top-right coordinate of r1

// x2_1, y2_1 = top-left coordinate of r2
// x2_2, y2_2 = top-right coordinate of r2

double a1 = Math.abs(x1_1-x2_2);
double a2 = Math.abs(x1_2-x2_1);
double b1 = Math.abs(y1_1 - y2_2);
double b2 = Math.abs(y1_2 - y2_1);

return !(a1>0.001 && a2>0.001 && b1>0.001 && b2>0.001);
```

Oftentimes, I could see that the x coordinates are indeed similar or close to each other, but based on the actual image, they are not intersecting. Here is a demonstration:

[image: non-intersecting rectangles]

In this image, I drew a red line to describe that the two rectangles "kind of intersect" in terms of the code, which does not satisfy an actual intersection. I think it was the fact that I had to check the y-coordinates as well but I'm no longer sure of how to do that because I think I have to check a range of values.

I hope I could get some help as to see if a rectangle intersects another or is beside another rectangle. Perhaps using a library or a modification on my existing code because it is not working as it should. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect) to work with rectangles, and check [intersection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#intersect(android.graphics.Rect)) in particular:

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(left1, top1, right1, bottom1);
Rect r2 = new Rect(left2, top2, right2, bottom2);

boolean result = r1.intersect(r2);
```

---

If you need float coordinates, you can use [RectF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've checked this but I can't use it because its constructor only accepts integers based on the docs. I need to use double values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It was working but not all of the time for my use-case so I had to modify my algorithm because of my specifications - which makes the rectangles intersect sometimes or I had to check if one is beside another. 

Thank you very much for the help!